# Play Framework how do i set a "-D" option in sbt run?

Tags: playframework

I need to set

-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true

Using sbt run, how do i do this? Is it in a config file or... something?

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?
sbt -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true run